# Unable to build scss from examples with @use

Tags: css, sass

I'm unable to build .css file from scss no matter what I try.

I get the following error:

```
Error: Invalid CSS after "  color: c": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ".$accent-color;"
    on line 4 of sass/c:\MAMP\htdocs\testowy\sass\styles.scss
    color: c.$accent-color;
```

The files I'm using:

_colors.scss:

```
$accent-color: #535353;
```

styles.scss:

```
@use 'uses/colors' as c;
body {
  color: c.$accent-color;
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio Code and I have tried two different compiler extensions.

File structure:
[image]

Comment: Is `_colors.scss` in the same directory as `styles.scss`?

Comment: @disinfor yes. I have added the file structure to the question.

Comment: The problem is that `@use` loads CSS and SCSS files. As you can see, your `_colors.css` is first, so it will get loaded first and it will not contain any variables. None of your `_` (partials) files should compile on their own - or at the very least should compile in another directory. Check the settings in VSC and make sure that you don't compile `_` files. Move the CSS files out of that directory and then test it.

Comment: @disinfor still got the same problem. I have updated the question with new structure. I have also added ignore rule for files that begin with "_". Any other ideas?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Has anyone found a solution?